# Replace 'add new' with 'select existing' for an object on the admin page in Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin, admin

I think this is fairly simple, but I'm new to Django and I can't find any questions that match mine.

Here is my model--

```
class Team:
    # attributes for team

class Driver:
    # attributes for driver
    team = foreign_key(Team, blank=True, null=True)
```

Now each team is required to have three drivers, and some drivers will not belong to any team. In the admin panel, when I create a new team, I'm only able to get "Add a new driver" and you fill out the driver details. Instead, I want that replaced with a drop down box of the drivers that already exist in the system that don't already have a team.

I know I have to use Driver.objects.filter(team__isnull=True) somewhere...but where exactly is holding me up. I read about creating my own form, but not sure how to proceed. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking that the following will let you achieve what you want. You can use this to limit the number of Driver objects attached to a Team as well.

I would also make sure to check the number of Driver objects on a team in the Driver save method; this would ensure that if you are adding Driver objects to a Team from the Driver admin page (i.e. creating a Driver object and selecting a Team for it there and then) you don't get too many Driver objects attached to a Team.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects